# Adjoint matrix symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra

The matrix 
$$
A=\left ( \begin{matrix}
1 &1  &0 \\ 
 0&0  &0 \\ 
 0&0  &0 
\end{matrix} \right )$$ has 
$$
\text{adj } A=\left ( \begin{matrix}
0 &0  &0 \\ 
 0&0  &0 \\ 
 0&0  &0 
\end{matrix} \right ), 
$$
which is symmetric. Please show an example of a non-symmetric matrix, but its adjoint is symmetric.

Comment: Did you try working with the definition of the *Adjugate matrix* and find such matrix?

Comment: If you prove that the adjoint matrix is symmetric, I want another example other than the one that shows

Comment: I don't understand your question. Didn't you provide an example of what you're after?

Comment: The words *adjoint* and *adjugate* are not synonyms for most modern authors.  The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) gives a brief account of historical or "classical" usage.  Nowadays most Readers will understand *adjoint matrix* to mean the (conjugate) transpose.

Answer (score 0):

Let 
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 &1  &1 \\ 
 0&0  &0 \\ 
 0&0  &0 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}. 
$$
Then the [adjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) (adjunct) of $A$ is 
$$
\text{adj}(A)= 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 &0  &0 \\ 
 0&0  &0 \\ 
 0&0  &0 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}. 
$$
Thus $A$ is nonsymmetric but $\text{adj}(A)$ is symmetric.

Here is another example: 
$$
B= 
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 &1  &0 \\ 
 0&0  &0 \\ 
 1&1  &0 \\ 
\end{pmatrix} 
$$ 
 is nonsymmetric while
$$
\text{adj}(B) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 &0  &0 \\ 
 0&0  &0 \\ 
 0&0  &0 \\ 
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
is symmetric.